# What is a byte value (Assembly)

Tags: assembly, byte, bit, masm

I'm new to assembly programming, my first homework is to make a program that reads a byte value, and displays it back to the screen. My problem is, I'm not sure what they mean by byte value. I know what bytes are, do they mean a binary value? An 8 bit long input that can only have 1s and 0s? If that's what they meant, they would write binary value, wouldn't they? (Obviously I tried asking the teacher, he doesn't respond.) We are using MASM611 if I'm not mistaken. Sorry for lack of information, I'm new to this.

Comment: A byte is (typically) composed of 8 bits. However, it isn't usually displayed or entered as 8 binary digits. Rather, you may want another base like decimal or hexadecimal. Eg 26h hexadecimal = 38 decimal = 0010_0110 binary. Hexadecimal numbers from 0 to 0FFh can be stored in an unsigned byte, or equivalently decimal numbers from 0 to 255.

Comment: By the term "byte" they could mean character, as in single byte character, as they all were back in the old days (before variable length and/or multi-byte characters like unicode and such), and still are on some educational systems.  I think this is a likely interpretation of the instructions, since others are more complex and/or no reason to be limited by byte (e.g. might as well read an integer value and redisplay it).  So, I would say they are asking for simple input & output, here one (simple) character's worth.

Answer (score 2):

A byte value is an unsigned or signed integer value that fits in an 8-bit byte<sup>1</sup>.

The value of a byte (or word or dword) can be represented in many different ways for input and output, or in source code.

For example, an ASCII string of decimal digits (like "0" to "255" for unsigned, or -128 to +127 for 2's complement if you support a leading minus sign when parsing input.)  You don't necessarily have to range-check, you could just truncate your result to a byte.

Or a string of hex digits or even a string of base-2 digits (`'0'` and `'1'` ASCII characters), both of which are discussed in [How to convert a binary integer number to a hex string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53823756/how-to-convert-a-binary-integer-number-to-a-hex-string)

Or raw binary bytes from `ReadFile` / `WriteFile` Windows system calls, or loading/storing to variables in memory.

Or as ASCII characters, since an ASCII code takes 7 bits, and we just pad them to 8 bit and store them in bytes.  In source code this looks like `mov al, 'z'` which is exactly equivalent to `mov al, 122` and to `mov al, 7Ah`.

---

The wording of your assignment implies they want some form of text input and output, probably base-10 (decimal) ASCII digits.  Although you could probably pick hex.  And they want you to convert the input string to a 1-byte integer, then format it back again.

Like in *[DOS assembly read two succeeding characters, and convert to number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1640994/dos-assembly-read-two-succeeding-characters-and-convert-to-number)* and similar questions - the answer has decimal-string to integer for 2-digit input strings.  For output, see [Displaying numbers with DOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45904075/displaying-numbers-with-dos) (which includes more complicated code for 32-bit integers in 16-bit mode.)  Also [How do I print an integer in Assembly Level Programming without printf from the c library? (itoa, integer to decimal ASCII string)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13166064/how-do-i-print-an-integer-in-assembly-level-programming-without-printf-from-the/46301894#46301894) for the algorithm basics.

---

**Footnote 1:** The context is x86 assembly language so we can be 100% sure that assuming 8-bit bytes is ok.  Some early pre-x86 computers had other byte sizes, like 9-bit with 18 or 36-bit words.

Answer (score -3):

There is a byte value, a word, a double word and a double quad word in assembly, it is a collection of 8 bits/2 nibbles, a byte represent a little endian formatted byte present in the memory or register, which you can access by using 'byte [memory/register]' in assembly x8086, likewise for accessing a word use 'word'.

mov si, 0
mov ax, 0xFF0F
mov [ds:si], ax
mov al, byte [ds:si]

which will access 'byte' present on [ds:si+0], because it is formatted in 'little endian'.